# ¿ Como llamar a un Selector en Jquery?

Tags: jquery

El problema es que no se como llamar en jquery  a selectores que estan dentro de un div en jquery , lo necesito porque   en mi codigo hacia las funciones bien pero al asignarle  un contenedor  a los divs que son llamados por el query  ya no hace toda la funcion  de los eventos como remover

```
<div id="campoBusq"></div>

<div id="cont-categoria" class="centFRH">
    <div id="categoria">';
         include("selectCategJquery.php");  
   </div>
</div>


<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {

            $('#categoria').on('click','.elemento',function() {
               var e = $(this).clone();
               var identificador = $(this).attr("iden");

               if($("#campoBusq").find("."+identificador).length){

               }else{
                 $(e).appendTo('#campoBusq');
               } 
           });

            $('#campoBusq').on('click','.elemento',function() {
               $(this).remove();
            });

        });
  </script>
```

**Asi  es la vista**

*Cuando le doy click; el debe mostrarce en el div que trabaja como un imput y al darle  click al contenido que se agrego; ella se remueve pero el detalle  es que antes le daba click a los elementos del campoBusq y al de categoria y se removia de donde se asigno que seria campoBusq pero el que no funciona es categoria ya que le doy click  y ya no lo remueve esto paso luego de asignar nuevos divs como contenedor *

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Asi va el Nuevo diseño**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se entiende bien la pregunta. ¿Podrías formularla mejor? Tampoco se ve más o menos cómo son tus selectores, los cuales imagino vendrían de este archivo `include("selectCategJquery.php"); ` ¿Podrías mostrar algunos de los selectores? Se puede accerder a ellos por jQuery a través de la clase: https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/ o a través de la id del elemento `<select ... id="mi_selector"></select>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ese comportamiento me imagino que en algún momento estuvo donde ahora hay un espacio en blanco

```
if($("#campoBusq").find("."+identificador).length){
    // Aquí iría el código para remover
} else {
    $(e).appendTo('#campoBusq');
}
```

Estrictamente para que un selector remueva un elemento de su misma clase dentro del div `#campoBusq` tendría que quedar:

```
if($("#campoBusq").find("."+identificador).length){
    $("#campoBusq").find("."+identificador).remove()
} else {
    $(e).appendTo('#campoBusq');
}
```

Comment: Listo men acabo de probar el codigo y sirve de maravilla muchas graciasss